# Why is Flash obj invisible in FF, works great in IE, Safari, Chrome?

Tags: firefox, flash

I'm working with a WordPress plugin. It adds a flash player to the output page. All works great on IE, Safari, Chrome.

In FF 3.0.13, I can see via Firebug that the object is there, but it is grayed out.

```
Display == inline
Visibility == visible
```

So why isn't it visible? Ideas much appreciated.

Page: http://podcasts.pardesusa.org/  look in the paragraph that starts "Listen" at the end of the post.

Thanks for any ideas,

Larry

ps. Adblock is disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me in FF. Might be your FF plugin problem. Check whether you have installed your FF flash plugin properly. Try reinstalling the plugin.

Comment: Thanks. You were exactly right, a problem with the flash install. Re-installing Flash didn't help, perhaps it was some mime mix-up. After completely deleting and then re-installing FF, worked fine.